# Error Loading Image Files on iOS with Latest Corona SDK Build

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk

As of yesterday, image files were being pulled from the image folder correctly to build character models, but now most of the calls to display.newImageRect result in a black rectangle. This glitch only occurs on iOS, not in Android or the Simulator. Any suggestions?

There have been no changes to the code involved with loading images.

Corona: v2014.2393
OSX: 10.9.5 
XCode: 6.1

There are no messages in the console that would indicate being unable to load the images or anything of that nature, and the issue is that it works in the simulator, and on Android. However, when the application is built for iOS, the error occurs when building character models and loading most of the images, but, curiously, using the exact same module in another scene (a far less complicated scene) works still. Texture memory used stands around 15MB. I don't know, if that might be the cause of the error, but I'm fairly certain that it isn't. As I said, the curious thing is that a build from 2 days ago still works and loads the images just fine.

For clarity, all image files are PNGs.

UPDATE: The same bug occurs on earlier builds that previously functioned. So, this might be an issue with iOS or, at least, our app's compatibility with the latest version of iOS 8.

Using an older version of XCode and Corona seems to work only when building the older version of the application. Furthermore, purposely misspelling file names results in a different error. So, it's not that the images are not being found. Using the same image files in a working build on another machine doesn't produce the glitch either. Nor does transferring copying the modules for image loading over to the older build.

I'm seriously baffled.

Comment: check the spelling, capitalisation and extension of the image.

Comment: I have. It's all consistent, but I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reliably reproduce this issue, I suggest you ask on [Corona forums](http://forums.coronalabs.com/) or [report a bug](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/bug-submission) with them.

Comment: I posted to their forums when the issue first occurred. This is actually a reproduction of that same question. They asked for the version number and have since been silent.